# how to connect surface pro 3 to a vga monitor wirelessly

Tags: wireless-networking, vga, microsoft-surface

I have a surface pro 3 and would like to connect it wirelessly to a vga monitor but I can't work out how to do it! What hardware would I need? I would like not to have a dongle in the tablet, but rather use whatever is inbuilt to the surface and have the right hardware adapters at the monitor.
Thanks

Comment: Wirelessly you can't.

Comment: So a wireless vga adapter won't work?

Comment: We cannot do hardware/software recommendations here, it is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I am now using a wireless display adapter with a hdmi to vga converter, which seems to be (almost) working.
The one glitch is the WDA doesn't seem to support the same resolution + refresh rate that my vga monitor requires (when plugged in to my surface the in-built display adapter has the correct option), incidentally 1680x1050-60hz.
Is this inbuilt to the WDA? Or would a different converter that openly supports this mode fix it?

Comment: ...and because the refesh rate is not right my monitor keeps going to sleep. But before it does, the screen is actually connected wirelessly.